# Form of letters for safrut

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, safrus

Does anyone know of a good online resource for how to make the letters for Sefer Torah, tefillin, mezuzot, based on the Mishnah Berurah's Mishnat Sofrim (siman 36) or Keset Hasofer (Ch. 5), and/or other sources like Beit Yosef, Shulchan Aruch Harav, Aruch Hashulchan? I find these sources really really hard to read without pictures, just full of ambiguous phrases like "such and such is turned up" or "with a corner, but curved" (see Peh). And loads of others.
To me, that would include

1. Good sharp, full-sized pictures, with
2. Annotated text, with indications on exactly which part of the picture is indicated by a particular hard-to-read phrase, maybe with Right and Wrong pictures. Maybe lechatchilah/b'diavad pictures.
3. Alternate pictures for Ari Zal, Veilish, etc., for comparison.
4. Maybe alternate pictures if there is a machlokes on what the Mishnat Sofrim meant, etc.

In other words, not just pictures of the letters, but help from the pictures in learning these sources.
Someone pointed out to me that the poskim had pictures in front of them when they wrote their text, i.e., the written letter(s) themselves that they were describing. It's hard to replace that with words.

Comment: Be very skeptical of any suggestion offered here. A lot of these kinds of modern resources for scribes are not showing you what the author of some description meant, but rather how some old description could fit into some modern style of writing. The modern market forces people to categorize scripts into 4 groups (ashkenazi, chasidic, chabad, everyone else) but from a historical perspective that's basically a joke.

Comment: It’s advised to learn the letters directly from a G-d fearing sofer. I learned from two teachers the Arizal script and there were minor variations between the two. That doesn’t make one more right than the other, but one must acknowledge that each community has their custom that they follow.

Comment: @MenachemEliyahu Well, why can't a G-d fearing sofer extend his range of students by posting a class online? Some of us aren't getting out much right now. Here at least the lesson plan is clear: Aleph, Beit, ...

Comment: @DoubleAA "Be very skeptical of any suggestion offered here." I would, DoubleAA, if anyone would make some! What are these imperfect "modern resources for scribes"?

Comment: The full alpha beta (all 5) was printed in https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8 and this is a long sefer analyzing it https://hebrewbooks.org/53024 . Here is the Mishna Berura with some pictures https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94 and a different one in English https://hebrewbooks.org/49916

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @MichoelR Rav Eliezer Adam offers an online safrut course. He is based in Israel.